# list-packages: symbol's function definition is void

Tags: emacs

I can't use anymore `list-packages` inside emacs24 on ubuntu. Every time, I type `M-x list-packages`, I get:

```
"list-packages: symbol's function definition is void"
```

EDIT: 
I did `C-h f` list-packages, it loaded the corresponding page.

Comment: Please try to provide more information. The error message says that function `list-packages` is not defined. If `C-h f list-packages` does not recognize the function, try explicitly loading library `packages.el` -- put this in your init file: `(require 'package)`.

Comment: I did and I edited my post. It loaded the corresponding page.

Comment: Normally the list-packages command is an autoloaded command. This means that some special code is setup so that the command is available before the actual package/library which contains it is loaded. If your getting the void function error, it indicates that the autoload is not working for some reason. Try putting a (require 'package) in your init file to force loading of the library